# Nexus 7 is not being detected on Mac

Tags: nexus-7, usb-connection-mode, macos

Nexus 7 is only charging if it is connected to my mac. It is not being detected in Android Studio nor Android file transfer and there isn't anything popping up or showing a USB symbol on the Nexus. I enabled the "USB debugging" option in the Developer menu.
The connection mode was set by default to MTP.

Is there a problem with the cable, port or OS?

Comment: Can you see the device if you run `system_profiler SPUSBDataType` in Terminal.app?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Download the [Android File System application.](http://www.android.com/filetransfer/)

Install the Android File System app by opening the DMG file, and then dragging the App into your Applications folder.

[image]

Once installed, connect your Nexus 7 to your Mac via the USB cable.  Open up the Android File System app.  It should recognize your tablet and then open up a Finder type window.

[image]

You can drag and drop files and media into the window. Additionally, you can create new folders and delete files. Be sure you know what files your deleting as you can break the OS by deleting or altering essential system files.

[image]

If you get a “No Device Found” message, be sure your Nexus 7 is in `Media device (MTP)` transfer mode. You can do this by swiping down to open the notification tray and then tapping on the Connected As… message.

[image]

[Source](http://www.tech-recipes.com/rx/29608/google-nexus-7-how-to-access-files-from-a-mac/)

Comment: I don't understand why this was accepted since the question states the Nexus was *not* being detected in Android File Transfer.  Also, why do you say "Android File System" when all your screenshots show "Android File Transfer"?  I'm having [the same trouble myself](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/199632/190389), but the "it should recognize your tablet" step of your instructions is what isn't working.

Answer (score -1):

Connect your Nexus 7 to Mac via USB cable. Now go to Settings -> Developer options and turn On the USB debugging.

If you don't see Developer Options under Settings then, go to Settings -> About Tablet and tap on the Build Number multiple times (7 times) to enable the Developer Options.

Comment: *"I enabled the "USB debugging" option in the Developer menu."* -- did you not read the question?